# Postfix not sending email issues

Tags: centos, postfix

We have tried to run the postfix and just tried a simple command to send email

```
$ echo "test-1" | mail -s "TEst1" ****@gmail.com
```

Below is the results of `mailq`.

```
C110D80654      462 Sat Dec 29 13:33:34  root@localhost.localdomain
(Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=gmail.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
```

Tcp traceroute results stops at 5

```
tcptraceroute -n alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 587
Selected device eth0, address 192.168.2.10, port 60399 for outgoing packets
Tracing the path to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com (74.125.140.27) on TCP port 587 (submission), 30 hops max
 1  192.168.2.1  1.241 ms  0.228 ms  0.227 ms
 2  219.93.218.177  36.792 ms  37.132 ms  31.471 ms
 3  219.93.217.77  29.509 ms  33.459 ms  32.473 ms
 4  10.55.37.18  74.351 ms  38.381 ms  40.092 ms
 5  * * *

tcptraceroute -n alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
Selected device eth0, address 192.168.2.10, port 54214 for outgoing packets
Tracing the path to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com (74.125.137.26) on TCP port 25 (smtp), 30 hops max
 1  192.168.2.1  0.317 ms  0.234 ms  0.224 ms
 2  219.93.218.177  31.854 ms  33.550 ms  32.728 ms
 3  *
```

The best part I can yum update,install and even do wget. What could be issue here?

Comment: What does `dig mx gmail.com` say?

Comment: It seems to be the resolver issue. Try using the google resolver in `/etc/resolve.conf` file. Append the following entry `nameserver 8.8.8.8` or `nameserver 4.4.4.4` and check if that helps.

Comment: Maybe in chroot your resolv.conf is out of date. Look for this file in the /var. Chroot of postfix.

Comment: @SvenW I get this dig mx gmail.com
-bash: dig: command not found

Comment: @PratapSingh in my version is /etc/resolv.conf and I did the changes still not mail received.

Comment: @Andrew what to look for in /var?

Comment: Dear All any help on how to solve this email issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is postifx not able to resolve gmail.com:

> C110D80654      462 Sat Dec 29 13:33:34  root@localhost.localdomain
>   (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=gmail.com

And this is the system resolver able to resolve alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:

> Tracing the path to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com (74.125.140.27)

You're running postfix smtp(8) in a chroot (the third column in master.cf), and have not synchronized the chroot's resolv.conf with the system resolv.conf:

```
cp /etc/resolv.conf /var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: I tried to run the cp command but there is no /var/spool/postfix/etc folder. Another thing I dont get when your smtp(8) in a chroot third column in master.cf?